# How to assign dynamic Ids for ui:inputDate element inside aura:iteration?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, slds

As title says, How do I assign dynamic Ids for `ui:inputDate` elements inside `aura:iteration`?

Here is the reproducible version of the problem I am facing:

**HelloWorldApp.app**

```
<aura:application >
    <c:inputDateExample />
</aura:application>
```

**inputDateExample.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="datesList" type="List" />
    <table>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.datesList}" var="dateItem">
            <tr>
                <ui:inputDate aura:id="date-id" 
                              value="{!dateItem}" 
                              displayDatePicker="true"
                              blur="{!c.fldChanged}"/>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

**inputDateExampleController.js**

```
({
    fldChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Value changed');
        //How do I find from which date element, event is fired??
        //The below method finds both date elements because the Id is not unique
        var dateComponent = component.find('date-id');
        console.log(dateComponent);
        console.log(dateComponent[0].get("v.value"));
    },
    doInit : function(component,event,helper){
        var datesArray = [];
        datesArray.push("2017-01-01");
        datesArray.push("2017-01-31");
        component.set("v.datesList",datesArray);
    }
})
```

This produces the below output and I need to find which element user is clicking on??

[image]

**Notes:**

1. I can assign unique Id for tr element but not sure how to use that inside `component.find()` method.
2. I can assign dynamic id for plain `input` tags but there is too much markup involved for making these similar to lightning date element.
3. I tried giving html5 data attributes for `ui:inputDate` but it doesn' accept.

Any workarounds or anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `event.getSource()` to access the actual `ui:inputDate` component instance that fired the `blur` event.

`fldChanged` method should look like below:

```
fldChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('Value changed');
    // instance of the ui:inputDate which triggered the event
    var dateComponent = event.getSource(); 
    console.log(dateComponent);
    console.log(dateComponent.get("v.value"));
},
```

And to dynamically set aura:id to any component, you need to dynamically create them using `$A.createComponent()`

Comment: Can you please look at my other question when you get a chance? As suggested in your answer, I am trying to create component dynamically to give unique aura:Id attribute but running into some problem. Here is the link : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154212/how-to-create-inputdate-element-dynamically-inside-auraiteration Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @javanoob I believe there's no need to create inputDate with dynamic aura:id . You need compartmentalize the your component. BTW Mohit has answered your question please check it out.

Answer (score 3):

I Am not sure to assign dynamic Ids for `ui:inputDate` elements inside  `aura:iteration`.I have Workaround another method You can Know Which Date User Clicked On and which Element is Clicked .

Component 1:**testfordate**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="datesList" type="List" />
    <table>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.datesList}" var="dateItem" indexVar="indx">
            <tr>
                <c:testfordate2 SelectedId="{!indx}" date="{!dateItem}"/>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

Component 1: **Controller**

```
({

    doInit : function(component,event,helper){
        var datesArray = [];
        datesArray.push("2017-01-01");
        datesArray.push("2017-01-31");
        component.set("v.datesList",datesArray);
    }
})
```

Component 2:**testfordate2**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="SelectedId" type="String"  />
     <aura:attribute name="date" type="Date"  />
             <ui:inputDate aura:id="date-id" 
                              value="{!v.date}" 
                              displayDatePicker="true"
                              blur="{!c.fldChanged}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Component 2:**Controller**

```
    ({
          fldChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
            console.log('Value changed');
              var selectedid = component.get("v.SelectedId");
              console.log("user clicked",selectedid + 1 );
            var dateComponent = component.find('date-id');
            console.log(dateComponent);
            console.log(dateComponent.get("v.value"));       
 }
    })
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like we can give dynamic id for "aura:id", if we create components dynamically. Which one do you recommend in this case: creating components dynamically or your above mentioned approach? Pls suggest. Thanks!